# shorting this code for click menu

Tags: jquery

Feel like this is a long way round of doing it. dont think the function var is needed but struggle to get this to work otherwise, i have changed the bottom part of the script to do onmouse leave but always target the wrong element.

script the looks for div to be clicked and then display ul and hide on mouseout:

```
$(function() {
    var toggleMenu = function(e) {
        var self = $(this),
            elemType = self[0].tagName.toLowerCase(),
            //get caller
            menu = null;
        if (elemType === 'a') {
            //anchor clicked, nav back to containing ul
            menu = self.parents('ul').not('ul#logo_menu');
        } else if (elemType === 'ul') {
            //mouseleft ul, ergo menu is this.
            menu = self;
        }
        if (menu) {
            menu.hide('medium');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.logo_menu').click(function(e) {
            $('ul#logo_menu ul').show('medium');
            console.log('div clicked');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        $('ul#logo_menu a').click(toggleMenu);
        $('ul#logo_menu ul').mouseleave(toggleMenu);
    });
});
```

when i target a. to be clicked it is easier to write?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a.drop').click(function(e) {
         $(this).next("div").show('slow');
         console.log('div clicked');
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     });
    $('li.mainmenudrop').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children("div").hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why have `$(function() {` _and_ `$(document).ready(function() {` separate? Combine those.

Comment: want to get rid of function to shorten the script? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is about as short as you can get it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.logo_menu').click(function() {
    $('#logo_menu ul').show('medium');
    return false;
  });

  $('#logo_menu a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('ul').not('#logo_menu').hide('medium');
    return false;
  });

  $('#logo_menu ul').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide('medium');
  });
});
```

Comment: Of course it is ;) youve just re compiled my minds compiler to be me structured thank you!

Comment: No problem. It takes a few tries but you'll get the hang of it.